# Create a list os Kotlin with de result of a repeated function

Tags: android, list, loops, kotlin, parameter-passing

I have a very long method that creates a list with the result of a function that adds two numbers:

```
private fun Add(one: Int, two:Int) : Int {

 return one + two
}

private val myList = listOf(
 Add(1, 2),
 Add(2, 3),
 Add(3, 4),
 Add(4, 5),
 Add(5, 6),
 Add(6, 7),
 Add(8, 9),
 ...
)
```

Is there a way in kotlin to create this list without always repeating the name of the "add" function?

I have tried with "with" and "apply" but I think I am not using it correctly.

Comment: Will it work?  `private val myList = listOf(3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 17, ...)`

Comment: Nop, the function "Add" have two params.. the list contains the results of the sum of the two parameters

Comment: Is there some pattern of how you use `Add` function? Is it a  Fibonacci sequence?

Comment: How do you determine what numbers should be added?

Comment: are randomly generated numbers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If numbers are randomly generated then you can use some loop to fill the list, e.g.:

```
private val myList = genarateAndAdd(20)

private fun generateAndAdd(count: Int): List<Int> {
    val list = mutableListOf<Int>()
    repeat(count) {
        list.add(Add(Random.nextInt(), Random.nextInt()))
    }
    return list
}
```

where `count` is the size of the `myList` list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
import java.util.Random

val random = Random()

val myList = (0..<size of your list>).map{add(random.nextInt(), random.nextInt())}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
private val myList = listOf(
    Add(1, 2),
    Add(2, 3),
    Add(3, 4),
    Add(4, 5),
    Add(5, 6),
    Add(6, 7),
    Add(8, 9)
)
```

you can write this

```
private val myList = listOf(
    1, 2,
    2, 3,
    3, 4,
    4, 5,
    5, 6,
    6, 7,
    8, 9
).chunked(2).map { Add(it[0],it[1]) }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to get needed list via Kotlin one-liner

```
val myList = List(<size of your list>) { n -> Add(n, n+1) }
```